# How to plot q[y_, t_] , using x = x[y_, t_] and t as the independent variables?

Tags: plotting

```
(*--- The original independent variables are y and t ---*)

q[y_, t_] := y * t;
x[y_, t_] := y + t;

(*--- then x, t as the independent variables is I needed like {x,-10,10} ---*)
p1 = Plot3D[q[x[y, t], t],{y, -10, 10},{t, -10, 10}]

(*This is the original functions: q[y_, t_] := 0.5 Sech[4 y - 0.25 t];
x[y_, t_] := y - 0.5 Tanh[4 y - 0.25 t]*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I present a solution which doesn't need `FindRoot&Co`

```
picy = Plot3D[q[y, t], {y, -2 , 2 }, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All];
ytq = picy[[1, 1]][[1]]; (* all points {y,t,q} *)
```

Evaluate `x[y,t]=y-1/2 Tanh[4 y-t/4]`

```
ytqx = Map[Join[#, {#[[1]] - 1/2 Tanh[4 #[[1]] - #[[2]]/4]}] &, ytq];
(* all points {y,t,q,x}*)
```

final plot(pointwise)

```
ListPointPlot3D[ytqx[[All, {-1, 2, 3 }]], AxesLabel -> {x, t, q}]
```

[image]

Resulting plot shows a surface which has single or double solution q[x,t]!

This result confirms result in @cvgmt's answer(method1)

Comment: (+1) good viewpoint.

Answer (score 8):

### Method-1

```
q[y_, t_] := 0.5 Sech[4 y - 0.25 t];
(*x[y_,t_]:=y-0.5 Tanh[4 y-0.25 t]*)

ContourPlot3D[
 x == y - 0.5   Tanh[4   y - 0.25   t], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{x_Real, t_Real, y_Real} :> {x, t, q[y, t]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "q"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]]
```

[image]

### Method-2

```
q[y_, t_] := 0.5  Sech[4  y - 0.25  t];
x[y_, t_] := y - 0.5  Tanh[4  y - 0.25  t];
Plot3D[q[y, t], {y, -2, 2}, {t, -10, 10}, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{y_Real, t_Real, q_Real} :> {x[y, t], t, q}], 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

### Method-3

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q[y_, t_] := 0.5  Sech[4  y - 0.25  t];
x[y_, t_] := y - 0.5  Tanh[4  y - 0.25  t];
Plot3D[x[y, t], {y, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{y_Real, t_Real, x_Real} :> {x, t, q[y, t]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "q"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]]
```

[image]

### Method-4

Does not show the full plot, do not know why,Thanks @UlrichNeumann, we limit the range of `y` to `{y,-2,2}`

```
q[y_, t_] := 
  0.5   Sech[4   y - 0.25   t];(*x[y_,t_]:=y-0.5 Tanh[4 y-0.25 t]*)
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, t, q[y, t]}, 
    x == y - 0.5   Tanh[4   y - 0.25   t]}, {{x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 
     2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
Region[reg, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> True, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "q"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]]
```

[image]

Comment: Degrease y-range `(*x[y_,t_]:=y-0.5 Tanh[4 y-0.25 t]*)
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, t, q[y, t]}, 
    x == y - 0.5 Tanh[4 y - 0.25 t]}, {{x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 
     10}, {y, -2, 2}}]; 
Show[DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-2, 2}}(*,
  MaxCellMeasure\[Rule].001*)], PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> True]`

Answer (score 4):

To plot q as a function of x and t, you may note that:

y == x-t;

Therefore:

```
Plot3D[q[x - t, t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The inversion of a function may need a root search like in your real problem:

```
Clear[y]
q[y_, t_] := 0.5  Sech[4  y - 0.25  t];
y[x_, t_] /; NumericQ[x] := 
 yy /. FindRoot[x - yy + 1/2  Tanh[4  yy - 1/4 t], {yy, 0}]
Plot3D[q[y[x, t], t], {x, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks a lot, there q x have simplified. This is the real: q[x_, t_] := 0.5 Sech[4 y - 0.25 t];
x[y_, t_] := y - 0.5 Tanh[4 y - 0.25 t]

Comment: Look at  the addendum in my answer.

Comment: @DanielHuber shouldn't it be `FindRoot[x - yy + 1/2 Tanh[4 yy - 1/4 t], {yy, 0}]` ?

Comment: @
Ulrich Neumann Of course you are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
q[y_, t_] := y * t;
x[y_, t_] := y + t;

(*--- I need the range are (x,-10,10) ---*)
p1 = Plot3D[q[x[y, t], t],{y, -10, 10},{t, -10, 10},RegionFunction -> Function[{y,t}, -10<=x[y,t]<=10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this axeslabel are still y,t not x,t.