# ContourPolarPlot or PolarContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

Is there a way of plotting r^2=t with just one plot and one equation?
With PolarPlot, I plot it with two equations:

```
PolarPlot[{Sqrt[t], -Sqrt[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: the plot with two curves]

I tried ContourPlot but failed because it is acutally a polar form equation.

Is there 'ContourPolarPlot' or 'PolarContourPlot' with which we can directly plot the polar equation with just one curve?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203867/polar-contour-plot-in-mathematica

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- At first draw the contour `r^2==t` then transform to polar coordinate  `{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}` by `DisplayFunction`.

```
ContourPlot[r^2 == t, {r, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 20 π}, 
 ContourShading -> None, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}]]
```

[image]

- Test another implicit form of polar graph for example `r == (r - Cos[t])^2`.

```
ContourPlot[r == (r - Cos[t])^2, {r, -3, 3}, {t, -3, 3}, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}], 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

- We can test the question in the comment. [Polar contour plot in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203867/polar-contour-plot-in-mathematica)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(* $DisplayFunction=ReplaceAll[{r_Real,t_Real}:>{r*Cos[t],r*Sin[t]}] *)
a = 1;
f = (r^2 - a^3/r) Sin[t]^2;
cValues = {0.00001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 
   3.2};
ContourPlot[f // Evaluate, {r, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 Contours -> cValues, ContourShading -> None, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, `DisplayFunction` is actually used like this! This is really cool!  But I have a question, is `DisplayFunction` a rule, not a function?

Comment: DisplayFunction is not listed in the options of ContourPlot. And there is not much about it in the document. So my ultimate question is how can we find answers without this community.

Comment: @metroidman `DisplayFunction` is an option for `Graphics` (`Options@Graphics`). In early versions of Mathematica, displaying graphics was not as automatic, and `DisplayFunction` was featured more prominently and used more often. E.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/TheMathematicaBook/APracticalIntroductionToMathematica/GraphicsAndSound/1.9.2.html

Comment: @metroidman I also only recently found the various applications of such function. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298093/72111

Answer (score 5):

### On postprocessing and `DisplayFunction`

My thought, when the question was first posted, was to postprocess the
coordinates (see below), as is often done when graphics need to be transformed.
Before I was ready to post, @cvgmt posted their answer.  At first I thought I'd
let it go, but [metroidman's
reaction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300017/contourpolarplot-or-polarcontourplot#comment738996_300018)
made me think some clarification was needed, at least for other site visitors.
Aside from the (ab)use of `DisplayFunction`, the difficulties in getting a
good-looking plot by transforming coordinates, some of which are apparent in the
examples, have yet to be explained. Aside from these reasons for this post,
the really cool is buried down there where you probably won't even find it.

Whether we use `Plot[]` or `ContourPlot[]` or simply `Graphics[]`,
there's no difference between the following three,

```
Plot[..., DisplayFunction -> f]
Show[Plot[...], DisplayFunction -> f]
Plot[...] // f
```

except that in the latter, the code is shorter and there is no mystery to anyone
reading the code how `f` is applied. Hence the most straightforward way is to
postprocess the graphics (I've usually done something similar to what @kglr does
in
[Polar contour plot in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203867/polar-contour-plot-in-mathematica)
when I know the coordinates are stored in a `GraphicsComplex`):

```
ContourPlot[r^2 == t
  , {t, 0, 8 Pi}, {r, -5, 5}
  , PlotPoints -> 4*15, MaxRecursion -> 3] /.
 Graphics[g_, opts___] :> Graphics[
   g /. GraphicsComplex[p_, rest__] :>
     GraphicsComplex[Function[{t, r}, r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}] @@@ p, 
      rest]
   , PlotRange -> All (* needed *)
   , Ticks -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> Automatic, Axes -> True (* cosmetic *)
   , opts]
```

What problems do all the extra options address, if any?

#### Problems and solutions

*1. Converting only coordinates.*
This form keeps the coordinate conversion from being applied to non-coordinate
pairs of numbers (or triples in the case of 3D graphics). Some graphics forms
are difficult to transform, like `Text[{0.7, 1.3}, {1.,0.83}, {0.,0.5}, {1.,1.}]`, but they rarely show up in straight plots. The best approach is to
make such annotations after coordinate conversion. This slight modification of
another answer fails, for instance, because the `PlotRange` is altered by the
`DisplayFunction`:

```
ContourPlot[r == (r - Cos[t])^2, {r, -3, 3}, {t, -3., 3.}, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{r_Real, t_Real} :> {r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}], 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

*2. Getting a smooth polar plot.*
The meshing and subdivision algorithms of the plotting function are based on
measures of lengths, areas, and angles in cartesian coordinates. When the
results are transformed, angles may be magnified and lengths and areas scaled.
The results may not look pretty. Hence we see larger settings than normal of
`PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.  It results in overkill for some regions of a
plot, but it's the most convenient way to get a smooth curve.  Unfortunately
there is no way other than trial and error to determine what is a sufficiently
high setting. The setting for `PlotPoints` that I chose, `4*15`, corresponds to
fifteen points per period, which is not a lot; so I bumped up `MaxRecursion` to
add more points where needed. In other examples in this Q&A, one sees `PlotPoints -> 80`
here and `PlotPoints -> 100` there.  These are rather high compared to the default
setting `PlotPoints -> 15`.  Also, if I change the domain for the angle
`t`, then I will probably have to change the `PlotPoints` setting, a minor
annoyance.

*3. Seeing the plot.*
The plot range in cartesian coordinates and the plot range in polar coordinates
are not the same. If `PlotRange` is set in the cartesian graph being
transformed, it needs to be reset in the polar plot. `PlotRange -> All` is
convenient for showing all the plot, which can be seen in some examples in this Q&A.
Generally, you may have to figure out how
to zoom in on a certain portion if `All` is not what you want to show.

### Historical notes on `DisplayFunction`

The intended use of `DisplayFunction` is to display the graphics, which as
[@goofy
notes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300017/contourpolarplot-or-polarcontourplot/300018#comment738997_300018)
was not originally automatic
(see [Basic questions about running Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/basic-questions-about-running-mathematica/2914#2914), for instance).
It was used to control whether the graphics were
to be displayed at all or to send the PostScript form of the graphics to another
stream. In V6 `Display[]` became obsolete
(see [What does DisplayFunction->Identity do to graphics functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5682/what-does-displayfunction-identity-do-to-graphics-functions)),
and the purpose of applying
`DisplayFunction` to graphics changed in the docs from "in order to display them" to "before
returning them." The examples still show different ways to display graphics,
and an example can be found in
[How to set the output be generated in a cell different from "Output"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70185/how-to-set-the-output-be-generated-in-a-cell-different-from-output/71345#71345).
Nowadays, it has been repurposed by the `"Marketing"` plot theme to add elements
to 3D plots; its usefulness is shown in
[How to get a black transparent background in Plot3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298480/how-to-get-a-black-transparent-background-in-plot3d/299584#299584)
In this way a plot theme would not conflict with a user-specified `Epilog`; however,
there would be a conflict with a user-specified `DisplayFunction`. A user might
be better off using `Epilog` to get the background effects of `"Marketing"`.

**A look at the evolving documentation**

From [V1](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/list122.pdf):

> `DisplayFunction` is an option for graphics functions that specifies the
> function to apply to the graphics primitives that are generated in order to
> display them.    <sub>The default setting for `DisplayFunction` is
> `$DisplayFunction`.  A typical setting is
> `DisplayFunction->Display[channel, #]&`. Setting
> `DisplayFunction->Identity` will cause graphics primitives to be
> returned, but no display to be generated.</sub>

V2 added sound and a `DisplayFunction` for sound objects; otherwise, the
documentation and intended use didn't change until V6. In V6, the default
setting for `$DisplayFunction` became `Identity` and `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`
output were automatically rendered. Another change in V6:

> `Show`, as well as functions like `Plot` and `Plot3D`, automatically apply the
> function specified by the setting for `DisplayFunction` before returning their
> results.

Prior to that, if graphics were returned, they were typeset as (literally) `-Graphics-`
or `-SurfaceGraphics-` etc.

### Polar contour plots

Code for `polarEquationPlot[]` may be found on Github or in the code dump below.

The function uses the FEM functionality to make a mesh that resolves the features
of the curve. It adds a few `MaxCellMeasure` options:

```
{ (* override with MaxCellMeasure->opts *)
 "Area" -> 10. (* refine if (polar) area greater *)
 , "Length" -> 0.65 (* refine if r*dt greater *)
 , "Angle" -> 0.25 (* refine if dt greater *)
 , "Curvature" -> 0.5 (* refine if curvature greater *)
 , "MinArea" -> 0.0005 (* stop mesh refinement *)
 }
```

Curvature estimation is numerical and not very good until the mesh is small.
`Graphics` options, some `ToElementMesh[]` options, and some plotting options should work.
Works on my examples; hope it works on yours; otherwise, I'll delete.
Not much in the way of error checking yet.

Load package (maybe someday I'll have time to put together a paclet for the WPR):

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mroge02/polarEquationPlot/main/polarEquationPlot.wl"]
```

Examples show both the generated plot and the mesh that was computed to create the plot.

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  polarEquationPlot[r^2 == t, {t, 0, 60}, {r, -8, 8}, 
   PolarAxes -> Automatic, Axes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> Large],
  getLastPolarMeshPlot[]
  }]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[{
  polarEquationPlot[(r - 2)^2 + t^2 == 9, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {r, -1, 5}, 
   PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic],
  getLastPolarMeshPlot[]
  }]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[{
 (* poor curvature refinement *)
 polarEquationPlot[
  10 Cos[(r - 1)]^2 + t^3 == 9, {t, -2.5, 2.5}, {r, -6, 6}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Curvature" -> 0.05}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
  Axes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> RGBColor[0.85, 0.8, 0.75]],
 getLastPolarMeshPlot[]
 }]
```

[image]

#### Code dump

```
(* polarEquationPlot` Package v0.1 \[LongDash] ToElementMesh[] *)

BeginPackage["polarEquationPlot`"];

polarEquationPlot // ClearAll; (* Main function *)
lastPolarEquationPlotData // ClearAll; (* plot data (for debugging) *)
getLastPolarMeshPlot // ClearAll; (* visualizes last mesh (for debugging) *)


Begin["`Private`"];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

(*"
 * Main Function
"*)

polarEquationPlot // Options = Join[
   {MaxCellMeasure -> Automatic},
   Normal@KeyDrop[Options@PolarPlot, {MaxRecursion, PlotPoints}]];
call : polarEquationPlot[f_, {t_, t1_, t2_}, {r_, r1_, r2_}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{data = createPlotData @@ Unevaluated[call]},
  iPolarEquationPlot[data] /; FreeQ[data, Failure | createPlotData]
  ]

(* TBD *)
$unimplementedOptions = {ColorFunction, ColorFunctionScaling, 
   EvaluationMonitor, Exclusions, ExclusionsStyle, LabelingSize, Mesh, 
   MeshFunctions, MeshShading, MeshStyle, PerformanceGoal, PlotLabels, 
   PlotLegends, PlotStyle, PlotTheme, RegionFunction, ScalingFunctions, 
   WorkingPrecision};

(*"
 * Utilities
 *   createPlotData - process arguments and make plotData structure
 *   polarCurvature - estimate curvature of f[r, t] == 0
 *   meshRefine - refine mesh by measuring size/curvature in polar space
 *   makePolarGrid - steal polar grid from ListPolarPlot
 *   toLine - convert an intersected triangle into a crossing line
 *   toPoint - convert a crossed edge into a point of intersection
"*)

polarCurvature // ClearAll;
polarCurvature[points_, fvalues_, r1_ : Automatic] := 
  Module[{r0, derivs, denom},
   r0 = Replace[r1, Automatic :> Abs@Mean[points[[All, 2]]]];
   (* quadratic appoximation *)
   derivs = 
    LeastSquares[Function[{t, r}, {1., t, r, t^2/2, r t, r^2/2}] @@@ points, 
     fvalues];
   denom = r0^2 derivs[[2]]^2 + derivs[[3]]^2;
   If[denom == 0,(* rare *)
    100.,(* arbitrary large curvature *)
    (r0^2 derivs[[2]]^3 - 2 derivs[[2]]^2 derivs[[3]] + 
        r0 derivs[[3]]^2 derivs[[4]] - 
        2 r0 derivs[[2]] derivs[[3]] derivs[[5]] + 
        r0 derivs[[2]]^2 derivs[[6]])/(denom)^(3/2) // Abs
    ]
   ];
(*"
 * meshRefine[] is used in iPolarEquationPlot[] to control refinement of mesh
 *    Parameters are defined by options processed by createPlotData[]
"*)
meshRefine // ClearAll;
(* parameters may be set by polarEquationPlot[] *)
$plotData = <|
   (* override with MaxCellMeasure->opts *)
   "Area" -> 10. (* refine if (polar) area greater *)
   , "Length" -> 0.65 (* refine if r*dt greater *)
   , "Angle" -> 0.25 (* refine if dt greater *)
   , "Curvature" -> 0.5 (* refine if curvature greater *)
   , "MinArea" -> 0.0005 (* stop mesh refinement *)
   |>;
meshRefine[f_][vertices_, area_] := Module[{midpoints, pts, vals, r0, dt},
   r0 = Abs@Mean[vertices[[All, 2]]];
   If[r0*area > $plotData["Area"],
    True,
    If[(0.9 + r0) area > $plotData["MinArea"] && 
      Abs@Total@Sign[f @@@ vertices] < 3,
     dt = Max[vertices[[All, 1]]] - Min[vertices[[All, 1]]];
     If[dt > $plotData["Angle"] || r0*dt > $plotData["Length"],
      True,
      midpoints = Mean /@ Partition[vertices, 2, 1, 1];
      pts = Join[vertices, midpoints];
      vals = f @@@ pts;
      polarCurvature[pts, vals, r0] r0*dt > $plotData["Curvature"]
      ],
     False]]
   ];
createPlotData // Options = Options@polarEquationPlot;
createPlotData[f_, {t_, t1_, t2_}, {r_, r1_, r2_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Module[{plotData = $plotData, F, maxCellValue},
   With[{ff = f /. Equal -> Subtract},
    F = Replace[Hold[t, r],
      {Hold[tt_, rr_] :> (Block[{tt = #1, rr = #2}, ff] &),
       Hold[tt_[_], rr_[_]] :> (Block[{tt, rr}, t = #1; r = #2; ff] &)
       }]
    ];
   If[! NumericQ@F[t1, t2],
    (* MESSAGE *)
    Return[Failure["InvalidFunction",  <|
       "MessageTemplate" -> 
        "Equation `Equation` did not evaluate to numeric values.",
       "MessageParameters" -> <|"Equation" -> f|>
       |>],
     Module],
    plotData["F"] = F
    ];
   If[! AllTrue[{t1, t2, r1, r2}, NumericQ],
    (* MESSAGE *)
    Return[
     Failure["InvalidDomain",  <|
       "MessageTemplate" -> "At least one of `Domain` is not numeric.",
       "MessageParameters" -> <|"Domain" -> {t1, t2, r1, r2}|>
       |>],
     Module],
    plotData["R"] = {r1, r2};
    plotData["T"] = {t1, t2}
    ];
   maxCellValue = OptionValue[MaxCellMeasure];
   If[NumericQ[maxCellValue],
    plotData["Area"] = maxCellValue,
    Switch[maxCellValue,
     {___Rule}
     , plotData = Merge[{plotData, maxCellValue}, Last]
     ; If[! VectorQ[Keys[$plotData] /. plotData, Positive],
      (* MESSAGE *)
      Return[
       Failure["InvalidMaxCell",  <|
         "MessageTemplate" -> 
          "Maxima cell bounds in `CellBounds` should be positive real \
numbers.",
         "MessageParameters" -> <|"CellBounds" -> OptionValue[MaxCellMeasure]|>
         |>],
       Module]],
     Automatic
     , Null,
     _
     ,(* MESSAGE *)
     Null (* ignore??? *)
     ]
    ];
   plotData["GraphicsOptions"] = 
    FilterRules[Flatten@{opts}, Options@PolarPlot];
   plotData
   ];
(*" Convert triangle to contour line
 *    Different signs => contour crosses edge
 *    Sign all equal => no contour line
 *    One vertex zero => contour line thru opp. edge if signs !=
 *    Two vertex zeros => contour line = edge
 *    Three vertex zeros => contour lines = all edges
"*)
toLine // ClearAll;
(*toLine[signs_,sum_,zeros_,idcs_]:= line;*) 
toLine[signs_, sum_, 3, idcs_] := 
  Partition[Transpose[{idcs, idcs}], 2, 1, 1]; (* what to do? *)
toLine[signs_, 3 | -3, zeros_, idcs_] := {}; (* no crossings *)
toLine[signs_, sum_, 2, 
   idcs_] := {{#, #} & /@ Extract[idcs, Position[signs, 0]]};
toLine[signs_, 2 | -2, 1, idcs_] := {};
toLine[signs_, 0, 1, 
   idcs_] := {{{#, #} &@First@Extract[idcs, Position[signs, 0]], 
    Extract[idcs, Position[signs, Except[0, _Integer]]]}};
toLine[signs_, 1, 0, 
   idcs_] := {Transpose@{{#, #} &@First@Extract[idcs, Position[signs, -1]], 
     Extract[idcs, Position[signs, 1]]}};
toLine[signs_, -1, 0, 
   idcs_] := {Transpose@{{#, #} &@First@Extract[idcs, Position[signs, 1]], 
     Extract[idcs, Position[signs, -1]]}};
(*"
 * Get crossing point from edge=idcs
"*)
toPoint // ClearAll;
toPoint[coords_, vals_, {i_, i_}] := coords[[i]];
toPoint[coords_, vals_, idcs_] := Cross[vals[[idcs]]] . coords[[idcs]]/
  Subtract @@ vals[[idcs]];
(*"
 * Get polar grid from ListPolarPlot
"*)
makePolarGrid // ClearAll;
makePolarGrid // Options = 
  FilterRules[
   Options@PolarPlot, {PolarAxes, PolarGridLines, GridLinesStyle, 
    PolarAxesOrigin}](*{PolarAxes\[Rule]Automatic,PolarGridLines\[Rule]\
Automatic,GridLinesStyle->Automatic,PolarAxesOrigin->Automatic}*);
makePolarGrid[0 | 0., OptionsPattern[]] := {};
makePolarGrid[r_?NumericQ, OptionsPattern[]] := First@DeleteCases[
    ListPolarPlot[{{0, r}}
     , PolarAxes -> OptionValue[PolarAxes]
     , PolarAxesOrigin -> OptionValue[PolarAxesOrigin]
     , PolarGridLines -> Replace[OptionValue[PolarGridLines]
       , {Automatic :> {Automatic, FindDivisions[{0, r}, 6]}
        , {theta_, Automatic} :> {theta, FindDivisions[{0, r}, 6]}}]
     , GridLinesStyle -> OptionValue[GridLinesStyle]
     , PlotRange -> All
     ]
    , _GraphicsComplex, Infinity];
(*"
 * Visualization of underlying mesh
"*)
getLastPolarMeshPlot // ClearAll;
getLastPolarMeshPlot // Options = Options@Graphics;
With[{
   polyStyles = {RGBColor[
     0.07843150501697072, 0.7098038624759535, 0.22745093193374122`, 1.], 
     RGBColor[0.9941176941165422, 0.9098039188905757, 0.5431372307229443, 1.],
      RGBColor[
     0.8078430800811591, 0.06666710941434106, 0.1490195899430818, 
      1.]}(*CountryData["Mali","Flag"]//DominantColors//MapAt[Lighter[#,
   0.5]&,#,2]&*),
   ptStyles = {Darker[Cyan, 0.5], Lighter@Blend[{Yellow, Darker@Orange}]}
   },
  getLastPolarMeshPlot[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := With[{
     mesh = lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"],
     vals = 1 + UnitStep@lastPolarEquationPlotData["ValuesOnGrid"]},
    Graphics[
     MapAt[
      Append[#, {FaceForm[], (mesh@
            "Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> EdgeForm@LightGray])[[1, 2, 2]],
          Point[Range@Length@vals, VertexColors -> ptStyles[[vals]]]
         }
        ] &,
      ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[mesh, VertexColors -> polyStyles[[vals]]],
      2],
     opts,
     Frame -> True
     ]
    ]
  ];

(*"
 * Internal plotter
"*)

iPolarEquationPlot // ClearAll;
$gridPadding = Scaled[0.06];
iPolarEquationPlot[data_] := Block[{$plotData = data},
   Module[{coords,(*vals,*)signs, crossed, lines},
    glurg = foo = {};
    lastPolarEquationPlotData = data;
    lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"] = ToElementMesh[
      Rectangle @@ Transpose@{data["T"], data["R"]},
      "MeshRefinementFunction" -> meshRefine[data["F"]],
      "MeshOrder" -> 1
      ];
    coords = lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"]@"Coordinates";
    lastPolarEquationPlotData["ValuesOnGrid"] = data["F"] @@ Transpose[coords];
    signs = 
     Sign[Threshold[lastPolarEquationPlotData["ValuesOnGrid"](*,
       AccuracyGoal?*)]];
    crossed = 
     Pick[lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"]["MeshElements"][[1, 1]], 
      Abs@Total[signs[[#]]] < 3 & /@ 
       lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"]["MeshElements"][[1, 1]]];
    murf = lines = Apply[Join,
       With[{s = signs[[#]]},
          With[{res = toLine[s, Total[s], Count[s, 0], #]},
           (*If[(*Count[res,{{x_,x_},{y_,y_}},Infinity]>1*)ArrayDepth[res]!=
           3,
           foo={foo,Inactive[toLine][s,Total[s],Count[s,0],#]}]*)
           foo = {foo, Inactive[toLine][s, Total[s], Count[s, 0], #]};
           res
           ]
          ] & /@ crossed
       ];
    With[{pr = Max@Abs[lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"]@"Bounds" // Last]},
     Graphics[{
       makePolarGrid[
        Replace[$gridPadding, {Scaled[relPad_] :> (1 + relPad) pr, 
          absPad_?NumericQ :> pr + absPad}], 
        FilterRules[lastPolarEquationPlotData["GraphicsOptions"], 
         Options@makePolarGrid]],
       "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
           Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ContourPlot]) // First,
       Line[#[[2]] {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]} &@Block[{res},
              Check[
               
               res = toPoint[coords, 
                 lastPolarEquationPlotData["ValuesOnGrid"], #],
               Echo[Length@Flatten@glurg + 1];
               ];
              glurg = {glurg, Hold[toPoint[
                  lastPolarEquationPlotData["Mesh"]@"Coordinates",
                  lastPolarEquationPlotData["ValuesOnGrid"],
                  #]]};
              res
              ] & /@ #] & /@ lines
       }
      , lastPolarEquationPlotData["GraphicsOptions"]
      , PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 
       If[MatchQ[PolarAxes /. lastPolarEquationPlotData["GraphicsOptions"], 
         True | Automatic], Scaled[.1], Automatic]
      , Frame -> False
      , Axes -> ! 
        MatchQ[PolarAxes /. lastPolarEquationPlotData["GraphicsOptions"], 
         True | Automatic]
      , Ticks -> ({#, #} &@
         Select[FindDivisions[{-pr, pr}, 8], -pr <= # <= pr &])
      ]
     ]]];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could tolerate plotting both parts by using same style, e.g.:

```
f[t_] := Sqrt[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
ParametricPlot[{f[t], -f[t]}, {t, 0, 20  Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]